# Spaces in hyperlink "href" removed automatically

Tags: node.js

I am creating a page to display all files in a particular folder using the below code

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
var files12 = fs.readdirSync(dir);
res.write('<tr><td>filename    </td><td>download file    </td></tr><br/><br/>');
for(var item in files12) {

 res.write('<tr><td><a href=/santanu/uploads/'+files12[item]+'>' +files12[item]+ '</a></td><tr><br/>');
          }
          res.end();
      }
```

what i am doing here is creating hyperlink with file name. Now the file which have spaces got separated.

see the **href** for "Health Insurace Policy", It have only ***Health*** where are rest of the string ? I am printing the same thing and it appears correctly on hyperlink text. Please let me know if further clarification is required.

[image: see the href for "Health Insurace Policy"]

Comment: you should [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) the href value.

Comment: i am not sure where to put UrlEncode? can you elaborate ? @Crowcoder

Comment: Apologies, my comment was stupid, somehow I missed this was js with Node.... Going back to sleep now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put double quotes around the href value. To be safe, you should probably also use encodeURIComponent() on the file name.

```
res.write('<tr><td><a href="/santanu/uploads/'+files12[item]+'">' + files12[item]+ '</a></td><tr><br/>');
```

Comment: I make it like this. 

 res.write('<tr><td><a href="/santanu/uploads/"'+files12[item]+'>' + files12[item]+ '</a></td><tr><br/>');

But doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You closed the double quotes too early. See the code in my answer.